# Restore AWS EC2 Windows Server 2012 R2 Administrator's password

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, passwords, windows-server-2012

The situation is:
- There is an EC2 instance with Windows Server 2012 R2, and the Administrator's password is lost.
- There is no other user accessible either.
- It is not an imported ovf instance, so there is no way to export it (or is there?).
- There is no EC2 Agent installed on the instance.
- I thought about using [Offline NT Password & Registry Editor](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/), but I don't know how to boot into it from an EC2 Instance.

What can I do to restore the password?

Answer (score 0):

AWS has documented the process, but there are certain requirements:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ResettingAdminPassword_EC2Config.html

If you created the instance from an imported image, or don't have EC2Config running, you may be out of luck.

You can still detach the volume from the instance, associate it with another instance, mount it, and from there extract any data you may need.

Comment: The EC2 Agent is a prerequisite for the link you've sent. I went through the tutorial with 2 other servers and it worked (Because they had the agent installed). Thank you :)\